# Abstract class or interface for translator objects on Android

Tags: java, android, generics

i want to abstract a translator service for the user.
I think to do in 2 ways:

Or interface with this method:

```
public void translate(T  origin, T1 source);
```

Or an abstract class with the same method, both with generic classes for use with classes that i need.

Witch its better, interface or abstract class?

How can i do this in android with generic classes?Because compiler says me

```
Cannot resolve symbol T
```

I hope i explain me correctly.

Comment: For me, if I'm defining a class that says "this is a thing, except that some details about the thing are missing that will be filled in by other classes", then I make it an abstract class, but if it's more like "this is just a list of methods that something else needs to implement", then it looks more like an interface.  It's not always clearcut.  Sometimes I spend too much time agonizing over the question, and then I just decide on something.  Your case looks more like an `interface` to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic parameters should appear in the interface (or abstract class) declaration :

```
public interface Translator <T,T1>
{
    public void translate(T  origin, T1 source);
}
```

As to whether an abstract class or an interface are more appropriate, that depends on whether the implementors of the interface (or sub-classes of the abstract class) can be seen as being of the same kind as the interface/abstract class or not. If the answer is yes, an abstract class is appropriate.

Comment: And why interface and not abstract class?